# Determining the Hermitian operator in a Foldy-Wouthuysen transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, dirac-matrices

I am following the mathematical steps of a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physe.2023.115682) and at some point the authors consider a transformed Hamiltonian of the form
$$
\mathcal{H}' = e^{iS} \mathcal{H} e^{-iS}.
$$
They then follow a proposal made by [Foldy and Wouthuysen](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.78.29), considering that the mass and momentum do not commute, to define the operator S as
$$
S = -\frac{i}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \beta \alpha p_x \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}},
$$
where $\alpha = \gamma^0 \gamma^1$ and $\beta = \gamma^0$ are matrices formed by the Dirac matrix representation in $(1+1)D$, given by
$$
\gamma^0 = 
\left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0
    \end{array}
    \right)
    \hspace{1cm} \textrm{and} \hspace{1cm}
\gamma^1 = 
\left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0
    \end{array}
    \right).
$$
Whith this, they conclude, among other things, that
$$
S = -\frac{1}{2}
\left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & -\frac{1}{m(x)} \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{1}{2m^2} \frac{dm(x)}{dx} \\
    \frac{1}{m(x)} \frac{d}{dx} - \frac{1}{2m^2} \frac{dm(x)}{dx} & 0
    \end{array}
    \right).
$$

I am having some problem getting in this matrix expression for $S$. I have considered $p_x = -i \frac{d}{dx}$ (with $\hbar = 1$) and
$$
\beta \alpha = 
\left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0
    \end{array}
    \right).
$$
Using the chain rule, I had
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \right) = - \frac{1}{2m(x)^{3/2}} \frac{dm(x)}{dx} = - \sqrt{m(x)} \frac{1}{2m(x)^2} \frac{dm(x)}{dx}.
$$
This gives me
\begin{align*}
S & = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \beta \alpha \sqrt{m(x)} \frac{1}{2m(x)^2} \frac{dm(x)}{dx} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \beta \alpha \frac{1}{2m(x)^2} \frac{dm(x)}{dx} \\
& = 
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & -\frac{1}{2m(x)^2} \frac{dm(x)}{dx} \\
    \frac{1}{2m(x)^2} \frac{dm(x)}{dx} & 0
    \end{array}
    \right).
\end{align*}

Seems like I missed something and I wonder what is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you figured this out a long time ago, but the differentiation acts as an operator on everything to the right, so you have to use the product rule: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\hat{A}=(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\hat{A})+\hat{A}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ for a general operator $\hat{A}$, where the parentheses emphasize the differentiation of $\hat{A}$. This yields the missing first term of $S$.